# Change symbol size in R function plotrix::polar.plot()

Tags: r, plot, visualization, plotrix

Is there a way to change the size of the plotted blue circles produced by:

```
library(plotrix)
polar.plot(1:36, seq(0,350,by=10), rp.type='s', point.col='blue')
```

Hopefully, there is some sizing parameter to this function.

[image]

Comment: I'm still in need with this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cex` seems to work. Try:

```
polar.plot(1:36, seq(0,350,by=10), rp.type='s', point.col='blue', cex = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I missed this on my own :)